# Grouping timestamp data into user sessions SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to classify actions done by users into sessions in a new column. The way I want to classify sessions is if an action is done within 15 mins of the previous action it is part of the same session.

So for a table like this, i want to have another column where the session is the userid + timestamp of the first action of the session.

| User_ID | Action | TimeStamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Action 1 | 12:03:00 |
| 1234 | Action 3 | 12:11:00 |
| 1234 | Action 4 | 12:34:00 |
| 1234 | Action 1 | 12:41:00 |
| 1234 | Action 6 | 12:46:00 |
| 1234 | Action 1 | 13:01:00 |

With the results being

| User_ID | Action | TimeStamp | Session |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Action 1 | 12:03:00 | User1234_12:03:00 |
| 1234 | Action 3 | 12:11:00 | User1234_12:03:00 |
| 1234 | Action 4 | 12:34:00 | User1234_12:34:00 |
| 1234 | Action 1 | 12:41:00 | User1234_12:34:00 |
| 1234 | Action 6 | 12:46:00 | User1234_12:34:00 |
| 1234 | Action 1 | 13:01:00 | User1234_13:01:00 |

As of now i can get a table with timestamps of when sessions start like this, using lag and filtering but i dont know how to combine this with the original table.

| User_ID | Session Start |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 12:03:00 |
| 1234 | 12:34:00 |
| 1234 | 13:01:00 |

I can get the data in either Postgres, Mysql or BigQuery's SQL platforms.

My current code to get the table is,

```
select userid, timestamp as session_start 
from
(
select *, timestamp_diff (timestamp - lag (timestamp, 1) over(partition by user_id order by timestamp)) as time_diff
from table
)
where time_diff > 900
or time_diff is null
```

Solution: The solution i found is to create the table similar to the one above and add another Lead column for the session start column and join condition of the timestamps to be in between the two session times

Comment: Postgres or MySQL?

Comment: I can work with either Postgres, Mysql or Bigquery SQL

Comment: Only ANSI SQL compliant?

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Search for sql gaps and islands - heres one https://bertwagner.com/posts/gaps-and-islands/

Comment: Can you display what you want your final output to be?

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform this action, it is necessary to compare rows therefore use
a database CURSOR:
https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-cursor/